# Ruby on Rails error in active relation, NoMethodError: undefined method 'methodname' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x00000002ab5908>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, model-associations, active-relation

Here is code of two models which have 1 to 1 association

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :e_user
  validates_presence_of :first_name
  validates_presence_of :last_name
  validates :password, presence: true, :length => { :minimum => 6}
  validates_uniqueness_of :email, :message => ": This email is already registered!"
  validates_presence_of :email  
end
```

Below is second model:

```
class EUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to : user
end
```

When i go to rails console and get a User from db, by doing

```
a = User.where(:id => 1)
```

I get a user in a. Now I want to get the e_user associated with a(if any it should return it or return null), but i get error message when i type a.EUser in console, error is

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `EUser' for  #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x00000002ab5908>from /home/faraz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/relation.rb:459:in `method_missing'
from (irb):3
from /home/faraz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:45:in `start'
from /home/faraz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /home/faraz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:40:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Regards

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, you have declared that `User` `has_one :e_user`. Thus, the correct relationship lookup is:

```
first_user = User.first
first_user.e_user
```

Second, the `where` ActiveRecord method returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object type. What you need is `User` object itself. Instead, use `find`:

```
a = User.find(1)
a.e_user
```

**An explanation**: the `where` method returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object which contains *all* class objects which meet the conditions in an array-like structure. However, even if `where` returns just a single record, that record will still be contained within that array-like structure; any instance methods on the retrieved class won't be accessible until you access the object *within* the `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

`find`, on the other hand, returns the first object *itself* that meets the specified condition (by default, ActiveRecord matches against the object `id`). Thus, any object returned by the `find` method has full utility and use over the instance methods and attributes defined for those class objects:

```
find_user = User.find(1)
where_user = User.where(:id => 1)

find_user.class
#=> User
where_user.class
#=> ActiveRecord::Relation

find_user == where_user
#=> false

find_user == where_user.first
#=> true
```

Comment: Try using the `find` method, instead of `where`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked with `a.e_user`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

   has_one :e_user

end

class EUser < ActiveRecord::Base

 belongs_to :user

end

a= User.find(1)
```

`a.e_user` #should retrieve the e_user assicated with a

**Edit**
You can check with where as like this

```
a = User.where(:id => 1)
euser = a.first.e_user
```

Comment: check your association in class EUser, and change like this :)